# Hibernate 3.3.2GA improperly loads bytea data from PostgreSQL 9.0 and all type mappings are correct

Tags: hibernate, postgresql

You may have a bytea column mapped as Hibernate type binary.  In java, the bytea data are appropriately represented as byte[].

When you set the data, it appears in your PostreSQL 9.0 database correctly.

For example:

```
            set( [ 1, 2, 0, 1, 255, 0 ] )
```

Shows in a normal SQL query output as as:

```
             \x010201ff00
```

When Hibernate calls your java set() routine to load the data, the data are incorrect.  All but the first byte are changed to the ASCII representation of the byte value. Breakpoint at the set() function and observe Hibernate calling with:

```
           set( [ 1, 50, 48, 49, 102, 102, 48 ] )
```

equivalently:

```
           set( [ 1, '2', '0', '1', 'f, 'f', '0' ] )
```

PostgreSQL 9.0 has changed its default bytea output from 'escape' to 'hex'.  This confuses (at least) the pre-9.0 versions of hibernate.

To resolve, edit the postgresql.conf file and change the setting for "bytea_output" from "hex" to "escape", restoring the old output format.  Restart your server.

```
...
#vacuum_freeze_min_age = 50000000
#vacuum_freeze_table_age = 150000000
bytea_output = 'escape'         # hex, escape  escape is REQUIRED BY  HIBERNATE 3.3.2GA
#xmlbinary = 'base64'
#xmloption = 'content'
...
```

Your sql query data will also now display in the more traditional octal form:

```
\001\002\000\001\377\000
```

Since hex is easier to read, anyone know how to configure Hibernate 3.3.2GA to understand the hex format?

Comment: As you're using an old hibernate version - are you also using an old postgresql driver ? properly handling bytea hex wasn't added until a year or 2 ago.

Comment: Thanks.  We're using hibernate-spatial, not yet released with Hbernate 3.6 support.  The entire kit has interdependencies on older packages: in this case postgresql-8.4-701.jdbc3.jar.  Seemed to work w/ 9.0, but this is a snare for the unwary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem isn't with Hibernate per se, but with the PostgreSQL JDBC driver that needs to decode this stuff. It's a known issue, the same happens with for example DBD::Pg in Perl.

This issue was fixed in the PostgreSQL JDBC driver last May, so you should be able to simply upgrade that. See: http://jdbc.postgresql.org/changes.html#version_9.0-dev800

Comment: Yep, http://jdbc.postgresql.org/download/postgresql-9.0-801.jdbc3.jar works fine so far.  Addresses the bytea hex issue.